# NRule: understanding sample

Tags: rule-engine, nrules

I haven't done much of C# for last few years and recently I was trying to use
NRules for rule engine implementation.

While going through the sample

```
    Context context = default;
    LastSeat lastSeat = default;
    Seating seating = default;

    When()
        .Match(() => context, c => c.State == ContextState.CheckDone)
        .Match(() => lastSeat) // <=== this one
        .Match(() => seating, s => s.RightSeatId == lastSeat.SeatId);
```

I couldn't get how the second line in `When()` method `.Match(() => lastSeat)` works because when I see the source code of match

```
public interface ILeftHandSideExpression
{

    public ILeftHandSideExpression Match<TFact>(params Expression<Func<TFact, bool>>[] conditions)
    {
       //some logic here 
        return this;
    }
}
```

and `() => lastSeat` doesn't return *boolean*, I couldn't get my head around this.

I tried mimicking minified version of those lambda around but couldn't  get much of idea.

Comment: I found the answer to it

Comment: It's great that you found the answer, but in case others who find this question are interested, the key point to understand with NRules is that C# DSL is not actually executable code - it is a fluent expression builder, and those match conditions are later compiled into the actual executable delegates.
That second match creates an expression to match any fact of the type `LastSeat`.

Comment: I  didnt understand the C# key words params the was creating a confusion, with params  key word in function arugument  passing empty arrway is not required